# Object is overwritten by new one in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I know there are similar questions related to this but none of them seems to solve the issue for me.

How do prevent the push method from overwriting the existing object in the array?

Pardon the variable `x` by the way.

```
const investorValues = state.investorSelected;
    const categoryValues = state.categoryCheckbox;

    const listAsFavourite = {
        listName: "",
        listDescription: "",
        listItems: {
            categories: [],
            investors: [],
        },
        saveAsOpen: state.saveAsOpen === false ? !state.saveAsOpen : state.saveAsOpen,
        saveAsComing: state.save

> Blockquote

AsComing === false ? !state.saveAsComing : state.saveAsComing
    };

    if (investorValues !== null) {

        listAsFavourite.listItems = {
            ...listAsFavourite.listItems,
            investors: investorValues
        }
    }

    if (categoryValues !== null) {
        listAsFavourite.listItems = {
            ...listAsFavourite.listItems,
            categories: categoryValues
        }
    }

    const saveFavouriteList = () => {
        const favouriteList = []

        if (state.favouriteListName === "") {
            alert.error("List must have a title")
        } else {

            const x =  {
                ...listAsFavourite,
                listName: state.favouriteListName,
                listDescription: state.favouriteListDescription
            }
            
            favouriteList.push(x);


            localStorage.setItem("FAVOURITE_lIST", JSON.stringify(favouriteList));

            alert.success("List created");

            removeFavouriteListModal();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of push why not try favoritelist=[...favoritelist,x]

Comment: A little hard to tell from that snippet, but seems like your creating a new empty array each time and only saving that single entry. Is there more to this you could share?

instead of `const favouriteList = []`  maybe something like `localStorage.getItem("Favourite_List")` first with a null check of course